# Better approach to multiple jboss instances

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I need create 4 Applications running in different ports within JBOSS EAP 7.

- APP A: Port 8080
- APP B: Port 8081
- APP C: Port 8082
- APP B: Port 8083

I know that i need use **port-offset** in standalone.xml to configure it. But i need separate server.log and stop/start for each instance. So i have 2 solutions:

1) Copy entire jboss folder for each project. i.e: jbossA, jbossB ...

2) Create a instances folder in jboss folder a use server.base.dir argument, like this: `-Djboss.server.base.dir=appA`

Which is the usual choice to multiple jboss instances ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- We use different server base directories, eg:

  - standalone_appA
  - standalone_appB
  - standalone_appC
  - standalone_appD
- We pass the `-Djboss.server.base.dir` argument to `standalone.sh`.
- We have different `standalone.xml` for every app as they require different subsystems. If they are all the same for your case you can link them instead of copying.

Comment: So, Should I use the server.base.dir argument ?

Comment: Thanks, i Will use it

Answer (score 1):

1) You can create 4 different base directories, by copying the standalone folder and -Djboss.server.base.dir argument while starting the server.

2) But it would be better if you use domain mode and create 4 different servers in 4 different server groups. This will better from resource management and performance perspective.

- You can keep autostart for each server to false and start and stop servers separately from management console or CLI.

  - Logs would be generated in respective server folders, which can be customized by setting path.

Comment: Thanks i Will try